# Convert custom delegate type to Action<Object>

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

I want to convert the below delegate type to Action type, but i am getting runtime error

```
internal delegate void ExecuteMenuClick(object Sender);
```

using reflection i am getting the MethodInfo of a method which have same parameters.

```
void SampleMethod(object Sender){}
```

Now, i have a command class implementation that takes Action as parameter. I want to create a delegate and pass it to the command class so that it gets invoked.

```
CommandExecutor loclCommand = new CommandExecutor((Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(ExecuteMenuClick), instance, methodinfo);
```

However, i ended up getting the following error

```
Unable to cast object of type 'sampleproject.ExecuteMenuClick' to type 'System.Action`1[System.Object]'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You passed the wrong delegate type in the call to `Delegate.CreateDelegate`. You should use the following instead, which passes `typeof(Action<object>)`, resulting in a delegate of the correct type.

```
CommandExecutor loclCommand = new CommandExecutor((Action<object>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Action<object>), instance, methodinfo);
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, but why it haven't worked with my code as the signature of the delegate type is same. Could you throw some light on this. I am just 3 months into C#